# how can I get the value from header in JMeter

Tags: java, python, selenium, jmeter

I have to get the specific values from Request Header -- referer

```
referer: https://xxx.xx.xx/xx/xx?programGroupName=xxx&fundraiserPageID=3041315&participantFirstName=Test&participantLastName=Testerson&displayName=Test%20Testerson&fundraiserPageURL=http://xxx.xxx.xx/wpa/xx/xxx
```

In above I have to get only fundraiserPageID value that is '3041315' and after that participantFirstName value 'Test' plus other values and then need to store in the previous defined variables, so that I can reuse in the next request.

[image]

I tied following attempt using regular expression and it shows nothing, I'm going something wrong, not sure how to define the regular expression for it etc...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you show in your screenshot, althugh it's a URL, it's part of a value of referer in **request header** and therefore you must choose radio button of `Request Headers` in `Field to check` parameter

Also put value in Match No. field, it's a required field according to [doc](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), use 1 for getting first match.

> For match number > 0, matching will stop as soon as enough matches have been found.

Answer (score 0):

Amend your Regular Expression Extractor configuration as follows:

1. Switch "Field to check" to `Request Headers`
2. Change your Regular Expression to `fundraiserPageID=(\d+)` as I see neither quotation marks nor trailing `>` in your original Referer header

   [image: JMeter Regular Expressions Extractor]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: no way, I used above both solution and it doesn't extract the values